# Is there ONE word for the phrase "(he) killed (him/it) with his bare hands"

Tags: single-word-requests

A man killed a tiger with his bare hands.

A man _______ a tiger.

Comment: I assume you want a word that's not specific to a method, so something like "strangle" isn't acceptable.

Comment: This is a very open-ended question and also not clear in its motivation. I would probably use the word _slaughtered_ in the sample sentence. (Without better context, it would be very difficult to nail down the best word on the tip of _your_ tongue.)

Comment: But, if the word is to replace the sentence as a whole, wouldn't that imply that the method is "with his bare hands" and therefore "strangle" *would* be appropriate? ( as one option... actually thinking it though I see your point better.... he could (in theory) "skin" the tiger with his bare hands killing the tiger.... hmm..... )

Comment: What have you [looked up](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/kill) so far? Note that *suffocate, strangle, asphyxiate,* even *drown* could all be done with bare hands and need no weapon. How are you going to judge which word is suitable? What are your criteria? But I don't think English has a single word for "weaponlessly killed".

Comment: *Manucide* perhaps?

Comment: Another possibility is to identify the man's bare-handedness as a modifier before the noun _man_, and then use any general verb for "killed" that you like. For example: "An unarmed man slew a tiger."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***throttled***, as defined in [the Wikipedia article on Strangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangling)

> Manual strangulation (also known as "throttling") is strangling with
>   the hands, fingers, or other extremities and sometimes also with blunt
>   objects, such as batons.

According to the Wikipedia article, throttling is a subset of strangling.  Strangling can also be accomplished by hanging (suspended with cord around the neck) or with a ligature around the neck, without suspension (garroting).

An e-book on [Forensic Pathology](http://www.forensicpathologyonline.com/e-book/asphyxia/throttling) by Dr. Dinesh Rao defines throttling as:

> Asphyxia produced by compression of the neck by human hands is called
>   throttling.

Your man (Tarzan ?) throttled that tiger.  No, not Tarzan; wrong continent.

*Addendum in Response to Comment that there is more than one way to kill a tiger with one's bare hands:*

Sure.  Piece of cake.  My vision of this is that you get on the tiger's back (i.e. away from the teeth and above the claws) and throttle the tiger from behind.  If the OP would allow a garrote, that would make things much easier.

Comment: @ermanen I stand by throttling as the only conceivable way to kill a tiger with one's bare hands.  Too much fur and ribs in the way to rip out the tiger's heart.  If  you insist on an experiment, I will notify PETA. :)

Comment: It should be noted that, as commonly used, "throttled" does not necessarily imply that the individual was strangled to death, only that he was choked.

Comment: @ermanen Is there a Murder SE?  If so, we should migrate this Q to them.  I have gone back to simple "throttle".  My reasoning:  If the OP's man did not throttle the tiger to death, but merely throttled him until the tiger choked, the OP's man would not live to tell the tale.  Now I am going away to tackle something simple: income tax.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a single word for this.

(The verb ***throttle*** does not imply the death of the target. Homer Simpson regularly throttles Bart with no apparent long-term ill effects:)[image]

English is a vastly descriptive language, but we don't have single words to cover every possible situation.  (Otherwise we wouldn't need to construct sentences, we could just exchange single words!)

Comment: How would you say:

Comment: I would normally say that killing a tiger with your bare hands is worthy of a paragraph or two.  :-)  However, if I were being brief about it, your original "killed a tiger with his bare hands" is fine; "he killed a tiger bare-handed" would be about as succinct as I could get.